# opencl local memory half threads from a group gets correct execution

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, gpu

I have written a kernel in opencl using local memory to get the faster execution. This is the first time I am using local memory. My global_work_size = 16 and local_work_size = 8.

Opencl kernel: mapper.cl

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable
typedef struct data
{
  double dattr[10];
  int d_id;
  int bestCent;
}Data;


typedef struct cent
{
  double cattr[5];
  int c_id;
}Cent;

__kernel void mapper(__global int *keyMobj, __global int *valueMobj, __global Data *dataMobj, __global Cent *centMobj)
{
    int bx   = get_group_id(0);    
    int tx   = get_local_id(0);
    int size = get_local_size(0);

    __local double localData[8][2];
    __local double localCent[2][2];
    __local int local_id[8];

    int index = tx + bx*size;

    int j,k,color=0;
    double dmin=1000000.0, dx;

    for(j=0; j<2; j++)
    {
          if(tx<2)
              localCent[tx][j] = centMobj[tx].cattr[j];

          localData[tx][j] = dataMobj[index].dattr[j];
          local_id[tx] = dataMobj[index].d_id;

    }
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE); 


    for(j=0; j<2; j++)     
     {
        dx = 0.0;
        for(k=0; k<2; k++)
            dx+= ((localCent[j][k] - localData[index][k]) * (localCent[j][k] - localData[index][k]));

        if(dx<dmin)            
        {  color = j;   
           dmin = dx;
        }
     }  
    keyMobj[index]   = color;
    valueMobj[index] = local_id[tx];
}
```

In the above kernel, I am fetching first 8 objects of structure dataMobj and 2 objects of centMobj from global memory to the local memory localData and localCent respectively. As far as my programming is concerned I have used the proper for loops for data fetching.

But it gives me correct execution for first 8 work-items(for the first work-group) only. It doesn't fetch the the data using next remaining 8 work-items for remaining block.

Please tell me how this exactly works and let me know if I am going wrong. I have also used the memory fence for thread synchronization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with this program is that you are going out of bounds of your array.  This explains why you are able to achieve proper results with only 8 work-items, but not with 16.

`localData` is an array of arrays of doubles in the `local` memory space:

```
 __local double localData[8][2];
```

We also have a variable `index`, which is defined as:

```
int index = tx + bx*size;
//get_local_id(0) + get_group_id(0) * get_local_size(0) = get_global_size(0)
```

The value of index ranges [0-15] in the case of 16 work-items.  On the following line:

```
dx+= ((localCent[j][k] - localData[index][k])
     * (localCent[j][k] - localData[index][k]));
```

the `localData` variable is referenced using the `index` variable even though the range of the local array can only be [0-8].

Comment: Clear me at this point. Suppose I am writing a program of computing square of first 512 numbers. I am using work-group size = 64. Suppose I am using local memory for the operation with tile size same as my block(work-group) size. So you mean I need not have to create 512 work-items?? Would 64 threads be enough for the operation as I am using shared memory??

Comment: Also, You said that my localData is referenced using the index which ranges [0-15]. But as I am using 8 work-items at a time to fetch the data from global to local memory, as well as to perform my computation. So index should compute its range from [0-7] according to its formula. 
I am in big confusion. Any weblink which has some examples on shared memory opencl would be really helpful.

Comment: @sandeep.ganage The main problem I think you are having is the difference between local addressing and global addressing.  The variable `index` you are using will give you the global ID for the work-item, which will be between 0 and the number of work-items you have.  In each work-group you create a local array of size 8.  You can only address that local array with indices between 0-7.  Even if it's thread 1024, it can only access this array with indices 0-7. Local data can't be shared with other work-groups.

Comment: @sandeep.ganage In regards to your squaring numbers example, you should have 512 work-items with work-group size = 64.  Each work-group will contain an array of 64 integers.  Each work-item in the work-group can be assigned to a block of that array based on the *local* ID (0-64).  The value to compute can be pulled in using the *global* ID (0-512).  E.g. work-item 129 will be in work-group 3 with a local ID of 1.  It will pull data from #129 in an *global* array and will place it in the *local* #1.  Then it will perform computations on *local* #1.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I have one last question for you on this. I hope you will show your kind interest in this one also..In the above problem of squaring 512 numbers, use of shared memory would really be that useful? Because if we consider the case of matrix multiplication, there is a data which is reusable and should be cached into the shared memory. But in this case neither of elements I have to use in future. So what are the performance benefits of using shared memory in my case??

Comment: @sandeep.ganage No.  There isn't going to be a performance benefit in this case.  Actually in this case there will likely be a performance detriment because of the extra access to local memory (which is slower than registers).  This was just a toy example given so that you could understand how the local memory and global memory were mapped.  In your original question, I'm not sure how big of an impact local memory usage will be, but I expect to be marginal at best.